# whitespace between slider and dots [slick]

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

When trying to make my slick slider responsive I get a problem with a whitespace between my content/sliding element and dots that I can't remove. When viewing the page on full screen (non responsive view), the dots are gone (I know why, and that's good), the whitespace is gone, but my arrows are in my content. Here is an image (N & O are the arrows, css is temporary missing):

whitespace problem:
[image]

arrows problem:
[image]

HTML CODE:

```
<section class="o-container u-mt-x2 u-bgcolor-white">
            <div class="o-grid">
                <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
                    <section class="o-container u-mt-x12">
                        <div class="c-card u-mb-x0">
                            <div class="o-container">
                                <div class="o-grid">
                                    <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12 u-12/12@lg u-mb-x6 u-text-center"><h2
                                                class=" u-text-center u-color-blue">Weitere Funktionen fur Anbieter</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                                            eirmod.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12 u-mb-x6 o-grid--equal-height">
                                <div class="c-funcslider slick-slider">
                                    <div style="height: 328px; text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-bgcolor-white u-text-center"
                                             style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <div class="c-card__body u-pt-x5 u-p-x5">
                                                <h4 class="h4">Logenplätze buchen</h4>
                                                <p class="u-color-slate-gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                                    sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                                                    nonumy
                                                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
                                                    diam
                                                    voluptua.</p>
                                                <h3 class="h3">ab 30 €* / Woche</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height: 328px; text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-bgcolor-white u-text-center"
                                             style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <div class="c-card__body u-pt-x5 u-p-x5">
                                                <h4 class="h4">Logenplätze buchen</h4>
                                                <p class="u-color-slate-gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                                    sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                                                    nonumy
                                                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
                                                    diam
                                                    voluptua.</p>
                                                <h3 class="h3">ab 30 €* / Woche</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height: 348px; text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-bgcolor-white u-text-center"
                                             style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <div class="c-card__body u-pt-x5 u-p-x5">
                                                <h4 class="h4">Logenplätze buchen</h4>
                                                <p class="u-color-slate-gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                                    sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                                                    nonumy
                                                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
                                                    diam
                                                    voluptua.</p>
                                                <h3 class="h3">ab 30 €* / Woche</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height: 348px; text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-bgcolor-white u-text-center"
                                             style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <div class="c-card__body u-pt-x5 u-p-x5">
                                                <h4 class="h4">Logenplätze buchen</h4>
                                                <p class="u-color-slate-gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                                    sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                                                    nonumy
                                                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
                                                    diam
                                                    voluptua.</p>
                                                <h3 class="h3">ab 30 €* / Woche</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height: 348px; text-align: center;">
                                        <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-bgcolor-white u-text-center"
                                             style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <div class="c-card__body u-pt-x5 u-p-x5">
                                                <h4 class="h4">Logenplätze buchen</h4>
                                                <p class="u-color-slate-gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                                    sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                                                    nonumy
                                                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
                                                    diam
                                                    voluptua.</p>
                                                <h3 class="h3">ab 30 €* / Woche</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-container">
                                <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12 u-12/12@lg u-text-center "><p
                                            class="p-mini text-center">
                                        * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                                        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Slider */

.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &.dragging {
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
    }
}
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: fixed;
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }

    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
.slick-slide {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        float: right;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
    }
    &.slick-loading img {
        display: none;
    }

    display: none;

    &.dragging img {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .slick-initialized & {
        display: block;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-vertical & {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
if ($('.c-funcslider').length > 0) {
    $('.c-funcslider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: false
                }

            }
        ]
    });
}
```

I would say I need to edit it in my css or html but already tried a lot of things in those 2 files..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then share the link. Thanks

Comment: your slide height is different first 2 - 328px & last 3 - 348px